# sum function vs long addition

Tags: python, performance, cpython, built-in

I am wondering if the sum() builtin has an andventage over a long addition ?

is

```
sum(filter(None, [a, b, c, d]))
```

faster than

```
a + b + c + d
```

assuming I am using CPython ?

thanks

EDIT: What if those variables are Decimals ?

Comment: I'd guess the only difference is that `sum` is already implemented in the interpreter, while `a+b+c+d` needs to be interpreted first. I doubt there's a big difference, though.

Comment: Why exactly are you `filter`ing here? Assuming all your values are actually numeric, I'd assume it would be faster to just add the zeros instead of doing a separate pass to exclude them first.

Comment: @Karl, no idea my coworker modified my code I tought he had some reason to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick example (note that, to try to be fairer, the `sum` version takes a `tuple` argument, so you don't include the time for building that structure `(a, b, c, d)`, and doesn't include the unnecessary `filter`):

```
>>> import timeit
>>> def add_up(a, b, c, d):
    return a + b + c + d

>>> def sum_up(t):
    return sum(t)

>>> t = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> timeit.timeit("add_up(1, 2, 3, 4)", setup="from __main__ import sum_up, add_up, t")
0.2710826617188786
>>> timeit.timeit("sum_up(t)", setup="from __main__ import sum_up, add_up, t")
0.3691424539089212
```

This is pretty much inevitable - `add_up` doesn't have any function call overhead, it just does 3 binary adds. But the different forms have different uses - `sum` doesn't care how many items are given to it, whereas you have to write each name out with `+`. In an example with a fixed number of items, where speed is crucial, `+` has the edge, but for almost all general cases `sum` is the way to go.

With `Decimal`s:

```
>>> t = tuple(map(Decimal, t))
>>> a = Decimal(1)
>>> b = Decimal(2)
>>> c = Decimal(3)
>>> d = Decimal(4)
>>> timeit.timeit("add_up(a, b, c, d)", setup="from __main__ import sum_up, add_up, t, a, b, c, d")
0.5005962150420373
>>> timeit.timeit("sum_up(t)", setup="from __main__ import sum_up, add_up, t, a, b, c, d")
0.7599533142681025
```